# How to build node-libcurl with curl-impersonate

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, node-libcurl

I'm trying to build [node-libcurl](https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl) with [curl-impersonate](https://github.com/lwthiker/curl-impersonate)
But I guess I'm unable to compile with this binding.gyp

```js
'variables': {
    # Comma separated list
    'curl_include_dirs%': '/home/sonisins/live/hehe/install/include',
    'curl_libraries%': '/home/sonisins/live/hehe/install/lib',
    'curl_static_build%': 'false',
    'curl_config_bin%': '/home/sonisins/live/hehe/install/bin/curl-config',
    'node_libcurl_no_setlocale%': 'false',
    'node_libcurl_cpp_std%': '<!(node <(module_root_dir)/scripts/cpp-std.js)',
    'macos_universal_build%': 'false',
  },
```

Here's my folder struct incase if something feels missing
[image]